# Density of state vs energy

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Please bear me for this naive question.

In the definition of density of state in 3D we know that DOS $\rho(E)$ varies as $E^{\frac{1}{2}}$ i.e as energy increase it should increase. But when I see the  experimental value/graph it shows that DOS increasing and decreasing in some fashion.

I can't understand the decreasing part. 
Here I am giving the picture

[image]

Please let me know the reason for the decreasing portion of the graph.

Comment: Well, the density of states of *what* are you computing when deriving the $\propto E^{1/2}$, and is silicon such a thing?

Comment: Yes, Si might not be a good example. Please see this figure for Cu and Ni. http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/consider-cu-ni-density-states-schematically-sketched-figure-chapter-4-problem-25-solution-9780072957914-exc

Answer (score 2):

The density of states $\rho(E) \propto E^{1/2}$ is valid only for free electrons.  Electrons in a solid are certainly not free, and the density of states is complicated.   Certainly:  the density of states is zero inside the band gap.

Comment: I get it. Can you please give me a reference where this is clearly explained?